# Sort a list of two different objects with one common property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two lists that are coming from an API that represent two different classes. I want to display the two lists according to their proprieties in one general list where the elements are sorted by their date.

I need to separate the two lists because the proprieties to display are different and they only share the Date.

I manage to display the two list separately but cannot merge the two... Does anyone have an idea on that? Thank you very much.

here is the .js and view:

.js:

```
function activityController($http) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.race= [];
    vm.try= [];

    vm.errorMessage = "";
    vm.isBusy = true;

    $http.get("/api/race")
    .then(function (response) {
        //Sucess
        angular.copy(response.data, vm.race);

    }, function (error) {
        //Failure
        vm.errorMessage = "Failed to load the data" + error;
    })

    $http.get("/api/try")
        .then(function (response) {
            //Sucess
            angular.copy(response.data, vm.try);
        }, function (error) {
            //Failure
            vm.errorMessage = "Failed to load the data" + error;
        })

    .finally(function () {
        vm.isBusy = false;
    });


}
```

View :

```
<div class="col-md-offset-7">
<div class="text-danger" ng-show="vm.errorMessage">{{ vm.errorMessage}}</div>
<wait-cursor ng-show="vm.isBusy"></wait-cursor>


    <ul class="well" ng-repeat="activities in vm.race| orderBy: 'date':true">
        <li> {{activities.title}}</li>
        <li>Date : {{activities.date | date :'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</li>
        <li>Temps : {{activities.time}}</li>

    </ul>

    <ul class="well" ng-repeat="activities in vm.try| orderBy: 'date':true">
        <li> {{activities.person}}</li>
        <li>Date : {{activities.date | date :'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</li>
        <li>Temps : {{activities.type}}</li>

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is:

```
<ul class="well" ng-repeat="activities in vm.getRacesAndTrys()| orderBy: 'date':true">
    <li> {{activities.title}}</li>
    <li>Date : {{activities.date | date :'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</li>
    <li>Temps : {{activities.time}}</li>
</ul>
```

With a function in your vm:

```
vm.getRacesAndTrys = function() {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < vm.try.length; i++) {
        var item = vm.try[i];
        result.push({
            title: item.person,
            date: item.date,
            time: item.type
        });
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < vm.race.length; i++) {
        result.push(vm.race[i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

This will create a combined array and also convert all the `try` objects so that their fields match that of the `race` objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes it works but with the fact the number of prop of the two objects is the same. Which will be different in the futur. But anyway your answer is the beginning of my solution. Thanks again.